# ResourceManager trying to load .resources not .resx file

Tags: .net, resourcemanager

I am trying to load a resx file in my .net website using:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager( "Project.Resource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() );
```

The Resource.resx file is in the folder App_LocalResources and is set to be embedded in assembly on build.

When I try to access the resx file using:

`rm.GetString( "key" );` or `rm.GetString( "key", culture );`

I get an error message:

> Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "Project.Resource.resources" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly "Project" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies
>   required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

Notice the .resources ... any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: Isn't a designer file also created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way you are using ResourceManager is wrong.
See this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Also note, when you open Visual Studio command prompt, & run resgen.exe, it says its used to convert resource files from one format to another (i.e. resx to resources).
I think, you will need to convert your file to resources from resx & then load it using resourceManager.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track ... I should not be using ResourceManager

I ended up using the <%$Resources: filename, key %> syntax in my page instead

Answer (score 21):

To load .resx into ResourceManager you need specify namespace

```
var rm = new ResourceManager("Namespace.ResxName", Assembly.GetAssembly());
```

or you can get ResourceManager for free if set Access Modifier inside Managed Resource Editor to Internal or Public, after that VS will generate ResxName.Designer.cs

```
var rm = ResxName.ResourceManager;
```

Comment: +1 for the method of accessing resources through the Designer code

Answer (score 5):

There's surprisingly simple way of reading resource by string:

```
ResourceNamespace.ResxFileName.ResourceManager.GetString("ResourceKey")
```

It's clean and elegant solution for reading resources by keys where "dot notation" cannot be used (for instance when resource key is persisted in the database).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which version of .NET Framework are you using.

Try channging the way how you bring the ResourceManager to life.

```
ResourceManager rm = 
     new ResourceManager("Project.Resource", 
                         System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_LocalResources"));
```

It should work.

This is also exposed as a static property of the automatically generated .designer.cs class of the concrete resorce manager.

Answer (score -1):

Add the .resx extension explicitly.

You can also use the auto-generated class and use its properties if that is suitable for your project.

Comment: If I add the .resx to the "Project.Resource" I get the same error but for the file Project.Resource.resx.resources

Comment: Sorry, I missed that your .resx is in App_LocalResources. None of my post applies...